# Trying to create javascript out put loop for various tasks

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use javascript to create tasks with a counter.  The script will lookup task entries and then create depending on what is within the DB.  For example - 

task 1 [timer 1]
task 2 [timer 2]
task 3 [timer 3]

Currently my output is like so

task 1 [timer 3]
task 2 [timer 3]
task 3 [timer 3]

My code is as follows -

```
{% if tasks %}

    {% for task in tasks %}

        <button class="button";>Complete!</button><p style="display: inline-block;font-weight: bold; color: red;">{{ task.task_name }}
            </p>
        <p></p>
        <p id='{{ task.id }}'; style="text-align: right;padding-right: 60px"></p>
        <p> <script>
                var countDownDate = new DateTime('{{ task.task_due }}').getTime();

                var x = setInterval(function() {

            var now = new Date().getTime();

            var distance = countDownDate - now;

            var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
            var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
            var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
            var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

            document.getElementById('{{ task.id }}').innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
            + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

            if (distance < 0) {
            clearInterval(x);
            document.getElementById('{{ task.id }}').innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
            }
                }, 1000);
            </script>
        </p>
        <p></p>
```

I appreciate any help, thanks

Comment: Normally when this happens, it's because you've accidentally created a closure - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures..

Comment: It's not a good idea to duplicate your code like that. The variables will be shared among the `<script>`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things to point out:

1. Setting all these `var`s in the body of the document means they're all scoped to the global `window` object, which means each loop overwrites the same variable. **This is why you're seeing the results of `timer3` in all three slots.**
2. (Minor issue) You've got extraneous semicolons in a few places in your HTML. No need for semicolons in HTML tags, unless they're *inside* the quotes of an attribute that accepts them (such as the `style=""` attribute).
3. (Minor issue) Be consistent with quote marks. A good general style principle is `"double quotes"` for HTML attributes, `'single quotes'` for strings in Javascript.
4. You're creating duplicate javascript code for every iteration of your `for task in tasks` loop. You should instead think of that loop as a place to *trigger the start of* timers and *display the results of* timers, but that shouldn't be where all that timer-creation code lives.
5. To fix (4), you'll want to make a reusable function out of the timer-creating code. This is a good test case to think about what function arguments you need to pass to a timer-creating function. In looking over your code, I see that you're using `task.id` and `task.task_due` in the code that creates the timer. Looks like we would just need to pass those two values to a `createTimer()` function.

#### Try something like this:

```html
<script>
  function createTimer(taskId, taskDue) {
    // just look this element up once for this timer
    var timerElement = document.getElementById(taskId);

    var countDownDate = new DateTime(taskDue).getTime();

    var timer = setInterval(function() {
      var now = new Date().getTime();
      var distance = countDownDate - now;

      if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        timerElement.innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
      } else {
        var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

        var timerDisplay = `${days}d ${hours}h ${minutes}m ${seconds}s`;
        timerElement.innerHTML = timerDisplay;
      }
    }, 1000);
  }
</script>


{% if tasks %}
  {% for task in tasks %}
    <button class="button">Complete!</button>

    <p style="display:inline-block; font-weight:bold; color:red;">
      {{ task.task_name }}
    </p>

    <p id="{{ task.id }}" style="text-align:right; padding-right:60px"></p>

    <!-- call the function to start this timer -->
    <script>createTimer('{{ task.id }}', '{{ task.task_due }}')</script>
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: That's has worked a treat and helped better my understanding of it all, thanks very much!